# Change color in java.awt.Image?

Tags: java, image-manipulation

I have an `java.awt.Image` object. It is an colorful image. Here is my code:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(bytes);
Image image = icon.getImage();
```

***How can I make it black & white?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into using a BufferedImageOp.  See [Drawing an Image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) in the Java Tutorials for more details.

Comment: I don't wanna use `Graphics` or `Graphics2D`.

Comment: @Harry Joy : Is there a reason why you don't want to use `Graphics`?

Comment: @Zach L: I have not used `Graphics` through out my app.

Comment: @Harry Joy : You can get the image's graphics through [Image.getGraphics()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getGraphics()). If you haven't used it because you don't want to, you should consider it; no need to reinvent the wheel.